# Is YAML disfavored as a way to represent REST documents exchanged between services? If yes, why?

Tags: rest, soa, yaml

XML and JSON are popular, but I'm wonder why YAML does not seem to be used as a way to represent documents returned by services in SOA.

YAML documents seem to have the advantage of being easy to compose by hand -- easier than either JSON or XML -- and then just submit using a simple tool like `curl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think there is anything specifically against YAML. It’s just that JSON is good enough. It’s simple, it’s deployed everywhere, it has lots of tooling, wrap it in a callback and you get cross-domain requests. And it’s not very difficult to write by hand either. Any format that wants to compete with JSON has to overcome its network effects, which is no trivial task.

XML is mostly just legacy, again subject to network effects.